# VBA, Check each row for certain condition - highlight then msgbox contains count of rows do not meet condition

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I have a column that I would like to check the value of each row. The first row does not start from row 1. The charachters in the cell can be number or lettter or combination of both. If the cell does not contain 9 charachters I would like to highlight them, then pops up a message box with count how many cell does not contain 9 characters. I use LEN formula  to count the characters.

Please help...

Comment: Do you want to check all the column's cell or just a selected range? What with empty cells - do you  want also higlight them?

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, try something like this. You must put worksheet name: (Sheet1) and range for scanning: (A3:A100):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'first clear all previous colors
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A100").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

counter = 0

For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A100")
   If (Len(c) <> 9) And (c <> "") Then
      c.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
      counter = counter + 1
   End If
Next c

If counter > 0 Then
   MsgBox counter & " cells has length <> 9", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Warning"
End If
End Sub
```